# How to merge CSS and JS into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 files, style.css, logic.js and container.html, while developing I need this files to exist separate, but when I am done, I'm searching for a tool that merges referenced css and js files into the HTML file:

```
<script src="./script/main.js"></script>
will turn into:

<script> ...code... </script>
and the same with CSS.
```

Is this possible? I first though this would be able with webpack, but the idea from webpack is not directly copying the content from the referenced files into the HTML file. Don't know if relevant, but I save my project on git and would like to run this build on bamboo, result of building my whole project should be one html file where all the code is inside, not being referenced, I could not find something that would do that?

Comment: I think you could config webpack to do that, although I don't know how exactly. You could also just create a bash script that edits the .html file and copies the contents of the other files into it.

Comment: There are only 3 files. You can just copy-paste them within one minute.

Comment: @Mezo Istvan with bash I don't think the solution would be scalable.

Comment: @holydragon, the 3 files is only an analogy to showcase the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a quick Google search gives me:

[html-inline](https://github.com/substack/html-inline)
[web-combiner](https://github.com/newghost/web-combiner)

Comment: hm, maybe I was searching with the wrong keywords, thanks, I will try them out.

Comment: My one useful skill is speaking Google... Glad I could help.

Comment: I tried out both and liked html-inline better since it does not requires C++ packages.